# Teams : Does the Card Editor (App Studio) have support to send adaptive card 1.2

Tags: microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

MS Teams : Does the Card Editor (App Studio) have support to send  adaptive card 1.2 ?
If so how do we send 1.2 cards here?

I only see support to send an JSON. However adaptive cards 1.2 are split into two, a card payload and an sample data.

Reference: 
https://adaptivecards.io/designer/

Answer (score 0):

Adaptive Cards is not "split into two" actually. Essentially, the final result that gets rendered to the user is a single combined JSON result. What I think you're talking about with "splitting" the card is a feature called "templating". You can read more about templating [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/templating/), and what it's trying to do is to separate the "design" of the card from the "data" (basically the values) you want to appear inside that card. For instance, your design would be saying something like "put the person's name here", and the data payload would be saying "and the name is 'Pavan'".

What that means in practice is that, yes, the Card Editor is still relevant, but it only works with the "design" part (it doesn't do templating). So it's good for helping see that the design works (e.g. by using the "Send this card to me" feature), but if you're using templating it won't help with that part.

Comment: Thanks Hilton,

I was checking on if there was an easier way to send 1.2 cards using card editor from the samples which now have a data and template JSON.

ex: https://adaptivecards.io/samples/CalendarReminder.html